# Issue during installation of RubyEncoder CLI mode

Tags: ansible

I am using RubyEncoder to encrypt my ruby application code and its working fine. But now we are providing on premise solution for our application. So we are creating image using packer. So we need to install RubyEncoder in that image so we can encrypt our code. But facing issue in installation of RubyEncoder.

Below is my ansible playbook:

```
---
- hosts: test1
  become: true
  tasks:
  - name: download rubyencoder tar file
    unarchive: src=https://www.rubyencoder.com/download.html?cm_id=151&action=download_file&id=c24f411ff92127c01f610f67e8a09aae dest=/home/dagar/rubyencoder copy=no
  - name: run rubyencoder
    become: yes
    become_user: dagar
    command: "{{ item }} chdir=/home/dagar/rubyencoder/rubyencoder-evaluation/bin"
    with_items:
        - /home/dagar/rubyencoder/rubyencoder-evaluation/bin/rubyencoder
```

I am aware that its asking for user input to continue i.e press `Enter` key many time as well accept the licence agreement by typing `I AGREE` as per below error:

```
failed: [testbed] (item=/home/dagar/rubyencoder/rubyencoder-evaluation/bin/rubyencoder) => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["/home/dagar/rubyencoder/rubyencoder-evaluation/bin/rubyencoder"], "delta": "0:00:00.006458", "end": "2019-08-12 11:18:27.808388", "item": "/home/dagar/rubyencoder/rubyencoder-evaluation/bin/rubyencoder", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 6, "start": "2019-08-12 11:18:27.801930", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "PLEASE READ THIS CAREFULLY BEFORE USING MATERIALS\r\n \r\nA. PROPERTY OF INOVICA \r\n\r\nYOU MAY OBTAIN A COPY OF THIS SOFTWARE PRODUCT EITHER BY DOWNLOADING IT\r\nREMOTELY FROM OUR SERVER OR BY COPYING IT FROM AN AUTHORISED DISKETTE, CD-ROM\r\nOR OTHER MEDIA ('HARD MEDIA'). THE COPYRIGHT, DATABASE RIGHTS AND ANY OTHER\r\nINTELLECTUAL PROPERTY RIGHTS IN THE PROGRAMS AND DATA WHICH CONSTITUTE THIS\r\nRUBYENCODER (VERSION 2) SOFTWARE PRODUCT (THE 'MATERIALS'), TOGETHER WITH\r\nTHE HARD MEDIA ON WHICH THEY WERE SUPPLIED TO YOU, ARE AND REMAIN THE PROPERTY\r\nOF INOVICA LIMITED ('INOVICA'). YOU ARE LICENSED TO USE THEM ONLY IF YOU\r\nACCEPT ALL THE TERMS AND CONDITIONS SET OUT BELOW.\r\n \r\nB. LICENCE ACCEPTANCE PROCEDURE \r\n\r\nBY CLICKING ON THE ACCEPTANCE BUTTON WHICH FOLLOWS THIS LICENCE AGREEMENT\r\n(MARKED 'I ACCEPT'), YOU INDICATE ACCEPTANCE OF THIS LICENCE AGREEMENT AND THE\r\nLIMITED WARRANTY AND LIMITATION OF LIABILITY SET OUT IN THIS LICENCE\r\nAGREEMENT. SUCH ACCEPTANCE IS EITHER ON YOUR OWN BEHALF OR ON BEHALF OF ANY\r\nCORPORATE ENTITY WHICH EMPLOYS YOU OR WHICH YOU REPRESENT ('CORPORATE\r\nLICENSEE'). IN THIS LICENCE AGREEMENT, 'YOU' INCLUDES BOTH THE READER AND ANY\r\nCORPORATE LICENSEE.\r\n \r\nPress return key to continue...C. LICENCE REJECTION PROCEDURE \r\n\r\nYOU SHOULD THEREFORE READ THIS LICENCE AGREEMENT CAREFULLY BEFORE CLICKING ON\r\nTHE ACCEPTANCE BUTTON. IF YOU DO NOT ACCEPT THESE TERMS AND CONDITIONS, YOU\r\nSHOULD CLICK ON THE 'REJECT' BUTTON, DELETE THE MATERIALS FROM YOUR COMPUTER\r\nAND PROMPTLY (AND IN ANY EVENT, WITHIN 14 DAYS OF RECEIPT) RETURN TO INOVICA\r\nOR A LICENSED RESELLER (A) THE HARD MEDIA; (B) ANY OTHER ITEMS PROVIDED THAT\r\nARE PART OF THIS PRODUCT; AND (C) YOUR DATED PROOF OF PURCHASE. ANY MONEY YOU\r\nPAID TO INOVICA OR AN INOVICA RESELLER FOR THE MATERIALS WILL BE REFUNDED LESS\r\nANY CREDIT CARD TRANSACTION FEE INCURRED BY INOVICA.\r\n \r\nD. OTHER AGREEMENTS \r\n\r\nIF YOUR USE OF THESE PROGRAMS AND DATA IS PURSUANT TO AN EXECUTED LICENCE\r\nAGREEMENT, SUCH AGREEMENT SHALL APPLY INSTEAD OF THE FOLLOWING TERMS AND\r\nCONDITIONS.\r\n\r\nLICENCE AGREEMENT AND LIMITED WARRANTY\r\n \r\n1. Ownership of materials and copies \r\n\r\nThe Materials and related documentation are copyrighted works of authorship,\r\nand are also protected under applicable database laws. Inovica retains\r\nPress return key to continue...ownership of the Materials and all subsequent copies of the Materials,\r\nregardless of the form in which the copies may exist. This licence is not a\r\nsale of the original Materials or any copies.\r\n \r\n2. Licence \r\n\r\n2.1. Evaluation Licence\r\nIf you have received an evaluation version of the Materials, Inovica hereby\r\ngrants to you, strictly for your own internal business purposes (and subject\r\nto the other terms and conditions of this Licence Agreement), a limited,\r\nnon-exclusive licence for a single user to:\r\n\r\n2.1.1. install the Materials for use on a single computer owned, leased and/or\r\ncontrolled by you for an evaluation period of 7 days;\r\n\r\n2.1.2. make a single copy of the Materials for back-up, archival or other\r\nsecurity purposes. \r\n\r\n2.2. Full Licence\r\nProvided that you have paid the applicable licence fee (and subject to the\r\nother terms and conditions of this Licence Agreement), Inovica hereby grants\r\nto you, strictly for your own internal business purposes, a limited,\r\nnon-exclusive licence for a single user to:\r\nPress return key to continue...\r\n2.2.1. install the Materials for use on a single computer owned, leased and/or\r\ncontrolled by you;\r\n\r\n2.2.2. make a single copy of the Materials for back-up, archival or other\r\nsecurity purposes.\r\n\r\n2.2.3. use RubyEncoder for development, testing, training and demonstration\r\npurposes and for the purpose of providing services to end users.\r\n \r\n2.3. Subject to the remaining provisions of this Licence Inovica grants to the\r\nLicensee a world-wide, royalty free, non-exclusive, licence to permit the\r\nLicensee to do the following things in relation to the Loader (being defined\r\nas the software program made available on the RubyEncoder website at\r\nwww.RubyEncoder.com in object code form that facilitates the conversion of\r\nscripts encoded with RubyEncoder to readable form). The following permissions\r\nshall be deemed to apply to and cover any use of the Loaders prior to the\r\neffective date of this Licence Agreement.\r\n\r\n2.3.1. Distribute free of charge and make copies of the Loader for non-revenue\r\ngenerating activities including but not limited to evaluation, development,\r\ndemonstration, training purposes, test, verification as well as for end user\r\nsupport. All such copies shall be subject to the provisions of this Licence\r\nPress return key to continue...Agreement;\r\n\r\n2.3.2. Merge, incorporate, install and integrate the Loader with any third\r\nparty or Licensee software;\r\n\r\n2.3.3. Use, distribute and market the Loader to end users provided always that\r\nend users are either (i) directed to the RubyEncoder website and agree to the\r\nterms of Inovica’s free Loader Licence or (ii) are supplied with a copy of\r\nInovica’s free Loader Licence when the encoded files are supplied.\r\n \r\n3. Limited Support\r\n\r\nInovica shall make available to you (at such times and to such extent as\r\nInovica may, in its sole discretion, deem reasonable) limited email support\r\nservices for a period of 6 months from the date of your first installation of\r\nthe Materials. Without prejudice to the foregoing provisions of this clause 3,\r\nsuch support services are, in any event, limited to your making a maximum of\r\n20 requests for assistance during the support period.\r\n\r\n4. Licence restrictions\r\n\r\nYou may not use, copy, modify or transfer the Materials (including any related\r\ndocumentation) or any copy, in whole or in part, including any print-out of\r\nPress return key to continue...all or part of any database, except as expressly provided for in this licence.\r\nIf you transfer possession of any copy of the Materials to another party or\r\nuse the Materials on a different computer from that on which the Materials\r\nwere originally installed except as provided herein or without obtaining\r\nInovica's prior written consent, your licence is automatically terminated. You\r\nmay not translate, reverse engineer, decompile, disassemble, modify or create\r\nderivative works based on the Materials, except as expressly permitted by the\r\nlaws of England and Wales. You may not vary, delete or obscure any notices of\r\nproprietary rights or any product identification or restrictions on or in the\r\nMaterials.\r\n\r\n5. No transfer\r\n\r\nThe Materials are licensed only to you. You may not rent, lease, sub-license,\r\nsell, assign, pledge, transfer or otherwise dispose of the Materials, on a\r\ntemporary or permanent basis, nor use the same for remote hosting, ASP\r\nservices, to act as a bureau or for time-sharing use without the prior written\r\nconsent of Inovica.\r\n \r\n6. Undertakings \r\n\r\nYou undertake to: \r\n\r\nPress return key to continue...6.1. ensure that, prior to use of the Materials by your employees or agents, \r\nall such parties are notified of this licence and the terms of this Licence \r\nAgreement;  \r\n\r\n6.2. reproduce and include our copyright notice (or such other party's \r\ncopyright notice as specified on the Materials) on all and any copies of \r\nthe Materials, including any partial copies of the Materials;  \r\n\r\n6.3. hold all drawings, specifications, data (including object and source \r\ncodes), software listings and all other information relating to the \r\nMaterials confidential and not at any time, during this licence or after \r\nits expiry, disclose the same, whether directly or indirectly, to any third \r\nparty without Inovica's consent. \r\n \r\n7.  Limited warranty \r\n\r\n7.1. Subject to the limitations and exclusions of liability below, Inovica\r\nwarrants that (a) the Hard Media on which the Materials are furnished  will \r\nbe free from material defects under normal use; and that (b) the copy of the\r\nprogram will materially conform to the documentation which accompanies the\r\nprogram. The Warranty Period is 90 days from the date of delivery to you.\r\n\r\n7.2. Inovica will also indemnify you for personal injury or death solely and \r\nPress return key to continue...directly caused by any defect in its products or the negligence of its\r\nemployees.   \r\n\r\n7.3. Inovica shall not be liable under the said warranty above if the\r\nMaterials fail to operate in accordance with the said warranty as a  result of\r\nany modification, variation or addition to the Materials not performed by the\r\nInovica or caused by any abuse, corruption or incorrect use or installation of\r\nthe Materials, including use of the Materials with equipment or other software\r\nwhich is incompatible.\r\n\r\n8. No other warranties \r\n\r\nThe foregoing warranty is made in lieu of any other warranties,\r\nrepresentations or guarantees of any kind, either expressed or implied,\r\nincluding, but not limited to, any implied warranties of quality,\r\nmerchantability, fitness for a particular purpose or ability to achieve a\r\nparticular result. You assume the entire risk as to the quality and\r\nperformance of the Materials. Should the Materials prove defective, you (and\r\nnot the Inovica nor any licensed reseller) assume the entire cost of all\r\nnecessary servicing, repair or correction. Inovica does not warrant that the\r\nMaterials will meet your requirements or that its operation will be\r\nuninterrupted or error free.\r\n \r\nPress return key to continue...9. Limitation of liability \r\n\r\nInovica's entire liability and your exclusive remedy shall be:\r\n \r\n9.1. the replacement of any Hard Media not meeting Inovica's 'Limited Warranty' \r\nand which is returned to Inovica together with dated proof of purchase; or  \r\n\r\n9.2. if, during the Warranty Period, Inovica is unable to deliver replacement \r\nHard Media which is free of material defects, you may terminate this Licence\r\nAgreement by returning the Materials to Inovica and any money you paid to\r\nInovica for the Materials will be refunded less any credit card transaction\r\nfee incurred by Inovica.\r\n\r\n10. Exclusion of liability\r\n\r\nExcept in respect of personal injury or death caused directly by the\r\nnegligence of Inovica, in no event will Inovica be liable to you or any third\r\nparty for any damages, including any lost profits, lost savings, loss of data\r\nor any indirect, special, incidental or consequential damages arising out of\r\nthe use of or inability to use such Materials, even if Inovica has been\r\nadvised of the possibility of such damages. Nothing in this Licence Agreement\r\nlimits liability for fraudulent misrepresentation.\r\n \r\nPress return key to continue...11. Your statutory rights\r\n\r\nThis licence gives you specific legal rights and you may also have other\r\nrights that vary from country to country. Some jurisdictions do not allow the\r\nexclusion of implied warranties, or certain kinds of limitations or exclusions\r\nof liability, so the above limitations and exclusions may not apply to you.\r\nOther jurisdictions allow limitations and exclusions subject to certain\r\nconditions. In such a case the above limitations and exclusions shall apply to\r\nthe fullest extent permitted by the laws of such applicable jurisdictions. If\r\nany part of the above limitations or exclusions is held to be void or\r\nunenforceable, such part shall be deemed to be deleted from this Licence\r\nAgreement and the remainder of the limitation or exclusion shall continue in\r\nfull force and effect. Any rights that you may have as a consumer (ie a\r\npurchaser for private as opposed to business, academic or government use) are\r\nnot affected.\r\n \r\n12. Term \r\nThe licence is effective until terminated. You may terminate it at any time by\r\ndestroying the Materials together with all copies in any form. It will also\r\nterminate upon conditions set out elsewhere in this Licence Agreement or if\r\nyou fail to comply with any term or condition of this Licence Agreement or if\r\nyou voluntarily return the Materials to us. You agree upon such termination to\r\ndestroy the Materials together with all copies in any form.\r\nPress return key to continue...\r\n13. Export\r\n\r\nYou will comply with all applicable laws, rules, and regulations governing\r\nexport of goods and information, including the laws of the countries in which\r\nthe Materials were created. In particular, you will not export or re-export,\r\ndirectly or indirectly, separately or as a part of a system, the Materials or\r\nother information relating thereto to any country for which an export licence\r\nor other approval is required, without first obtaining such licence or other\r\napproval.\r\n\r\n14. General\r\n\r\n14.1. You agree that Inovica shall have the right, after supplying undertakings \r\nas to confidentiality, to audit any computer system on  which the Materials\r\nare installed in order to verify compliance with this licence Agreement.\r\n\r\n14.2. This Licence Agreement constitutes the complete and exclusive statement \r\nof the Agreement between Inovica and you with respect to the subject matter of\r\nthis Licence Agreement and supersedes all proposals, representations,\r\nunderstandings and prior agreements, whether oral or written, and all other\r\ncommunications between us relating to that subject matter.\r\n\r\nPress return key to continue...14.3. Any clause in this Licence Agreement that is found to be invalid or \r\nunenforceable shall be deemed deleted and the remainder of this Licence\r\nAgreement shall not be affected by that deletion.\r\n\r\n14.4. Failure or neglect by either party to exercise any of its rights or \r\nremedies under this Licence Agreement will not be construed as a waiver of\r\nthat party's rights nor in any way affect the validity of the whole or part of\r\nthis Licence Agreement nor prejudice that party's right to take subsequent\r\naction.\r\n\r\n14.5. This Licence Agreement is personal to you and you may not assign, \r\ntransfer, sub-contract or otherwise part with this Licence Agreement or \r\nany right or obligation under it without the Inovica's prior written consent. \r\n\r\n14.6. This Licence Agreement and any claim or matter arising under or in \r\nconnection with this Licence Agreement and the legal relationships established\r\nby this Licence Agreement shall be governed by and construed in all respects\r\nin accordance with the law of England and Wales, and the parties agree to\r\nsubmit to the non-exclusive jurisdiction of the English courts.\r\n\r\nShould you have any questions concerning this Licence Agreement you may\r\ncontact Inovica Limited at Suite 20, Quay Level, St Peter's Wharf, Newcastle\r\nupon Tyne, NE6 1TZ. Email: support@rubyencoder.com.\r\nPress return key to continue...\nIf you have read and agree with the terms in the license agreement\ntype \"I AGREE\": You should read and agree with the terms in the license agreement\nto use this software.", "stdout_lines": ["PLEASE READ THIS CAREFULLY BEFORE USING MATERIALS", " ", "A. PROPERTY OF INOVICA ", "", "YOU MAY OBTAIN A COPY OF THIS SOFTWARE PRODUCT EITHER BY DOWNLOADING IT", "REMOTELY FROM OUR SERVER OR BY COPYING IT FROM AN AUTHORISED DISKETTE, CD-ROM", "OR OTHER MEDIA ('HARD MEDIA'). THE COPYRIGHT, DATABASE RIGHTS AND ANY OTHER", "INTELLECTUAL PROPERTY RIGHTS IN THE PROGRAMS AND DATA WHICH CONSTITUTE THIS", "RUBYENCODER (VERSION 2) SOFTWARE PRODUCT (THE 'MATERIALS'), TOGETHER WITH", "THE HARD MEDIA ON WHICH THEY WERE SUPPLIED TO YOU, ARE AND REMAIN THE PROPERTY", "OF INOVICA LIMITED ('INOVICA'). YOU ARE LICENSED TO USE THEM ONLY IF YOU", "ACCEPT ALL THE TERMS AND CONDITIONS SET OUT BELOW.", " ", "B. LICENCE ACCEPTANCE PROCEDURE ", "", "BY CLICKING ON THE ACCEPTANCE BUTTON WHICH FOLLOWS THIS LICENCE AGREEMENT", "(MARKED 'I ACCEPT'), YOU INDICATE ACCEPTANCE OF THIS LICENCE AGREEMENT AND THE", "LIMITED WARRANTY AND LIMITATION OF LIABILITY SET OUT IN THIS LICENCE", "AGREEMENT. SUCH ACCEPTANCE IS EITHER ON YOUR OWN BEHALF OR ON BEHALF OF ANY", "CORPORATE ENTITY WHICH EMPLOYS YOU OR WHICH YOU REPRESENT ('CORPORATE", "LICENSEE'). IN THIS LICENCE AGREEMENT, 'YOU' INCLUDES BOTH THE READER AND ANY", "CORPORATE LICENSEE.", " ", "Press return key to continue...C. LICENCE REJECTION PROCEDURE ", "", "YOU SHOULD THEREFORE READ THIS LICENCE AGREEMENT CAREFULLY BEFORE CLICKING ON", "THE ACCEPTANCE BUTTON. IF YOU DO NOT ACCEPT THESE TERMS AND CONDITIONS, YOU", "SHOULD CLICK ON THE 'REJECT' BUTTON, DELETE THE MATERIALS FROM YOUR COMPUTER", "AND PROMPTLY (AND IN ANY EVENT, WITHIN 14 DAYS OF RECEIPT) RETURN TO INOVICA", "OR A LICENSED RESELLER (A) THE HARD MEDIA; (B) ANY OTHER ITEMS PROVIDED THAT", "ARE PART OF THIS PRODUCT; AND (C) YOUR DATED PROOF OF PURCHASE. ANY MONEY YOU", "PAID TO INOVICA OR AN INOVICA RESELLER FOR THE MATERIALS WILL BE REFUNDED LESS", "ANY CREDIT CARD TRANSACTION FEE INCURRED BY INOVICA.", " ", "D. OTHER AGREEMENTS ", "", "IF YOUR USE OF THESE PROGRAMS AND DATA IS PURSUANT TO AN EXECUTED LICENCE", "AGREEMENT, SUCH AGREEMENT SHALL APPLY INSTEAD OF THE FOLLOWING TERMS AND", "CONDITIONS.", "", "LICENCE AGREEMENT AND LIMITED WARRANTY", " ", "1. Ownership of materials and copies ", "", "The Materials and related documentation are copyrighted works of authorship,", "and are also protected under applicable database laws. Inovica retains", "Press return key to continue...ownership of the Materials and all subsequent copies of the Materials,", "regardless of the form in which the copies may exist. This licence is not a", "sale of the original Materials or any copies.", " ", "2. Licence ", "", "2.1. Evaluation Licence", "If you have received an evaluation version of the Materials, Inovica hereby", "grants to you, strictly for your own internal business purposes (and subject", "to the other terms and conditions of this Licence Agreement), a limited,", "non-exclusive licence for a single user to:", "", "2.1.1. install the Materials for use on a single computer owned, leased and/or", "controlled by you for an evaluation period of 7 days;", "", "2.1.2. make a single copy of the Materials for back-up, archival or other", "security purposes. ", "", "2.2. Full Licence", "Provided that you have paid the applicable licence fee (and subject to the", "other terms and conditions of this Licence Agreement), Inovica hereby grants", "to you, strictly for your own internal business purposes, a limited,", "non-exclusive licence for a single user to:", "Press return key to continue...", "2.2.1. install the Materials for use on a single computer owned, leased and/or", "controlled by you;", "", "2.2.2. make a single copy of the Materials for back-up, archival or other", "security purposes.", "", "2.2.3. use RubyEncoder for development, testing, training and demonstration", "purposes and for the purpose of providing services to end users.", " ", "2.3. Subject to the remaining provisions of this Licence Inovica grants to the", "Licensee a world-wide, royalty free, non-exclusive, licence to permit the", "Licensee to do the following things in relation to the Loader (being defined", "as the software program made available on the RubyEncoder website at", "www.RubyEncoder.com in object code form that facilitates the conversion of", "scripts encoded with RubyEncoder to readable form). The following permissions", "shall be deemed to apply to and cover any use of the Loaders prior to the", "effective date of this Licence Agreement.", "", "2.3.1. Distribute free of charge and make copies of the Loader for non-revenue", "generating activities including but not limited to evaluation, development,", "demonstration, training purposes, test, verification as well as for end user", "support. All such copies shall be subject to the provisions of this Licence", "Press return key to continue...Agreement;", "", "2.3.2. Merge, incorporate, install and integrate the Loader with any third", "party or Licensee software;", "", "2.3.3. Use, distribute and market the Loader to end users provided always that", "end users are either (i) directed to the RubyEncoder website and agree to the", "terms of Inovica’s free Loader Licence or (ii) are supplied with a copy of", "Inovica’s free Loader Licence when the encoded files are supplied.", " ", "3. Limited Support", "", "Inovica shall make available to you (at such times and to such extent as", "Inovica may, in its sole discretion, deem reasonable) limited email support", "services for a period of 6 months from the date of your first installation of", "the Materials. Without prejudice to the foregoing provisions of this clause 3,", "such support services are, in any event, limited to your making a maximum of", "20 requests for assistance during the support period.", "", "4. Licence restrictions", "", "You may not use, copy, modify or transfer the Materials (including any related", "documentation) or any copy, in whole or in part, including any print-out of", "Press return key to continue...all or part of any database, except as expressly provided for in this licence.", "If you transfer possession of any copy of the Materials to another party or", "use the Materials on a different computer from that on which the Materials", "were originally installed except as provided herein or without obtaining", "Inovica's prior written consent, your licence is automatically terminated. You", "may not translate, reverse engineer, decompile, disassemble, modify or create", "derivative works based on the Materials, except as expressly permitted by the", "laws of England and Wales. You may not vary, delete or obscure any notices of", "proprietary rights or any product identification or restrictions on or in the", "Materials.", "", "13. Export", "", "You will comply with all applicable laws, rules, and regulations governing", "export of goods and information, including the laws of the countries in which", "the Materials were created. In particular, you will not export or re-export,", "directly or indirectly, separately or as a part of a system, the Materials or", "other information relating thereto to any country for which an export licence", "or other approval is required, without first obtaining such licence or other", "approval.", "", "14. General", "", "14.1. You agree that Inovica shall have the right, after supplying undertakings ", "as to confidentiality, to audit any computer system on  which the Materials", "are installed in order to verify compliance with this licence Agreement.", "", "14.2. This Licence Agreement constitutes the complete and exclusive statement ", "of the Agreement between Inovica and you with respect to the subject matter of", "this Licence Agreement and supersedes all proposals, representations,", "understandings and prior agreements, whether oral or written, and all other", "communications between us relating to that subject matter.", "", "Press return key to continue...14.3. Any clause in this Licence Agreement that is found to be invalid or ", "unenforceable shall be deemed deleted and the remainder of this Licence", "Agreement shall not be affected by that deletion.", "", "14.4. Failure or neglect by either party to exercise any of its rights or ", "remedies under this Licence Agreement will not be construed as a waiver of", "that party's rights nor in any way affect the validity of the whole or part of", "this Licence Agreement nor prejudice that party's right to take subsequent", "action.", "", "14.5. This Licence Agreement is personal to you and you may not assign, ", "transfer, sub-contract or otherwise part with this Licence Agreement or ", "any right or obligation under it without the Inovica's prior written consent. ", "", "14.6. This Licence Agreement and any claim or matter arising under or in ", "connection with this Licence Agreement and the legal relationships established", "by this Licence Agreement shall be governed by and construed in all respects", "in accordance with the law of England and Wales, and the parties agree to", "submit to the non-exclusive jurisdiction of the English courts.", "", "Should you have any questions concerning this Licence Agreement you may", "contact Inovica Limited at Suite 20, Quay Level, St Peter's Wharf, Newcastle", "upon Tyne, NE6 1TZ. Email: support@rubyencoder.com.", "Press return key to continue...", "If you have read and agree with the terms in the license agreement", "type \"I AGREE\": You should read and agree with the terms in the license agreement", "to use this software."]}
```

But i don't know how we can pass `Enter` key on the fly as well as how we can provide other user input like accept license agreement by `I AGREE` and user mail id for `registration`.

Can you please help me how we can fix this issue.

Comment: [expect](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/expect_module.html) might help.

Comment: @Vladimir, Thank you for your response. In my case i need to press `Enter` around 9 time because i am getting `Press return key to continue`. Now i need to use `Press return key to continue..."\n"` 9 time, or we have any other way? Please suggest. If possible please provide basic syntax.

Comment: @VladimirBotka, I have tried below config but still i am getting error:
```

Comment: ```
---
- hosts: test1
  become: true
  tasks:
  - name: a
    unarchive: src=https://www.rubyencoder.com/download.html?cm_id=151&action=download_file&id=c24f411ff92127c01f610f67e8a09aae dest=/home/dagar/rubyencoder copy=no
  - name: ab
    expect:
      chdir: /home/dagar/rubyencoder/rubyencoder-evaluation/bin
      command: /home/dagar/rubyencoder/rubyencoder-evaluation/bin/rubyencoder
      responses:
           'Press return key to continue...': "\n"
           'Press return key to continue...': "\n"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Vladimir mentioned you can use the `expect` module. I have a working example below, but there are a few things to keep in mind:

1. You need to have the pexpect library installed
2. For some reason the return code from `rubyencode` after successfully accepting the license is `9`, so this needs to be handled properly (anything other than a `0` is considering a failure
3. I have also included return code `8` in the checks, as this is the code when the command is successfully run but license acceptance is not required.

Example:

```
  - name: run rubyencoder
    expect:
      command: "/home/dagar/rubyencoder/rubyencoder-evaluation/bin/rubyencoder"
      responses:
        '.*Press return key to continue.*': ""
        '.*type "I AGREE".*': "I AGREE"
        '.*Your RubyEncoder profile e-mail.*': "foo@bar.example.com"
        '.*Your RubyEncoder profile password.*': "foobar"
    ignore_errors: yes
    register: result

  - fail:
      msg: rubyencoder failed to install
    when: result.rc not in [0, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. The config provided by you is working fine.  I have tried similar approach but i was doing one mistake i.e i am not adding `.*` in response so its not picking exact line. I was not aware that response can handle `regex`. Thanks once again.

Comment: Now all things are working fine but when i am encoding my code using rubyencoder i am getting error `Ruby 1.9.0 compiler error. Is your code compatible with Ruby 1.9.0?`. But we are using ruby2.6.3. Can you help me on this issue? Thanks.

Comment: You probably need to set the version on the command line with `--ruby <version x.y>`. Note however that it looks like only versions up to `2.5` are currently supported by rubyencoder. Perhaps try using `--ruby 2.5.0` and see if that works?